# weak convergence in $L^p$ plus convergence of norm implies strong convergence

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Having trouble with this problem. Any ideas?

Let $\Omega$ be a measure space. Let $f_n$ be a sequence in $L^p(\Omega)$ with $1<p<\infty$ and let $f \in L^p(\Omega)$. Suppose that
$$f_n \rightharpoonup f \text{ weakly in } \sigma(L^p,L^{p'})$$
and 
$$\|f_n\|_p \to \|f\|_p.$$

Prove that $\|f_n-f\|_p \to 0$.

Also, can you come up with a counter-example for the $L^1$ case?

Comment: Do you know that $L^p$ is reflexive for $1<p < \infty$ while it is not for $p\in\{1,\infty\}$?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since $1<p<\infty$, the space $L^p(\Omega)$ is uniformly convex. This follows from Clarkson's inequalities. Now we use the following theorem, which can be studied in Brezis' book on functional analysis (chapter III).

**Theorem.** Let $E$ be a uniformly convex Banach space, and let $\{x_n\}$ be a weakly convergent sequence in $E$, i.e. $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ for some $x \in E$. If $$\limsup_{n \to +\infty} \|x_n\| \leq \|x\|,$$ then $x_n \to x$ strongly in $E$.

Try to construct a counter-example in the $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$ topology.

Comment: I think I got one. Let $\Omega=(0,2\pi)$ and $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)+1$. Then $f_n \rightharpoonup 1 \text{ weakly in } \sigma(L^1,L^{\infty})$. Also, $\|f_n\|_1= 2\pi$ for all $n$. However, $\|f_n-1\|_1 = 4$ for all $n$ so we have NO strong convergence.

Comment: @chango: Thank you, I needed exactly the example you found above. You saved me quite a bit of time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

For those who are trying to solve Problem 6 in Stein and Shakarchi's *Functional Analysis*. Below is a solution that closely follows the formulation of the problem itself.

First we have the following two Clarkson inequalities. The proof of the first one can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258386/proof-of-clarksons-inequality). The proof of the second one can be found [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1936-040-03/S0002-9947-1936-1501880-4/S0002-9947-1936-1501880-4.pdf).

For $2 \leq p \leq \infty$ we have $$\left\|\frac{f+g}{2}\right\|_{L^p}^p + \left\|\frac{f-g}{2}\right\|_{L^p}^p \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(\|f\|_{L^p}^p+\|g\|_{L^p}^p\right).$$

For $1 < p \leq 2$ we have $$\left\|\frac{f+g}{2}\right\|_{L^p}^q + \left\|\frac{f-g}{2}\right\|_{L^p}^q \leq \left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\|f\|_{L^p}^p+\|g\|_{L^p}^p\right)\right)^{q/p},$$ where $1/p+1/q=1$.

As a result, $L^p$ is **uniformly convex** when $1 < p < \infty$. This means that there is a function $\delta = \delta(\epsilon) = \delta_p(\epsilon)$, with $0 < \delta < 1$, (and $\delta(\epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$), so that whenever $\|f\|_{L^p} = \|g\|_{L^p} = 1$, then $\|f-g\|_{L^p} \ge \epsilon$ implies that $\left\|\frac{f+g}{2}\right\|_{L^p} \le 1-\delta$.

Now suppose $1 < p < \infty$, and the sequence $\{f_n\}$ , $f_n \in L^p$, converges weakly to $f$, as well as $\|f_n\|_{L^p} \rightarrow \|f\|_{L^p}$. Without loss of generality we can assume $\|f\|_{L^p}=1$. There exists a $g \in L^q$ such that $\|g\|_{L^q} = 1$ and $\int_X fg = 1$. (Proposition 5.3 in Stein and Shakarchi.)

Define $f_n' = \frac{f_n}{\|f_n\|_{L^p}}$. It is easy to see that weak convergence, together with norm convergence, of $f_n$ implies that $\{f_n'\}$ also weakly converges to $f$. Therefore we have
$$\int_X \frac{f_n' + f}{2} g \rightarrow 1.$$

Now for any $\epsilon > 0$, take $\delta = \delta_p(\epsilon)$ as described previously with uniform convexity. There exists an $N$ such that for any $n>N$ we have
$$1-\delta < \int_X \frac{f_n'+f}{2}g < \left\|\frac{f_n'+f}{2}\right\|_{L^p} \left\|g\right\|_{L^q} = \left\|\frac{f_n'+f}{2}\right\|_{L^p}.$$

Uniform convexity then implies that $\|f_n'-f\|_{L^p} \le \epsilon$.

Since $\|f_n\|_{L^p} \rightarrow 1$, there also exists an $M$ such that $\|f'_n-f_n\| < \epsilon$ for all $n>M$. Now take any $n > \max(M,N)$ and we have
$$\|f_n-f\|_{L^p} = \|f_n - f_n' + f_n' - f\|_{L^p} \le \|f_n-f_n'\|_{L^p} + \|f_n'-f\|_{L^p} \le 2\epsilon.$$

This gives us the desired result.