# Weak convergence and $\|f_{n}\|\rightarrow\|f\|$ implies strong convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

> Let $\left\{ f_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in
>   $L^{p}\left([0,1]\right)$ for $p\geq1$. Suppose that there exists
>   $f\in L^{p}\left([0,1]\right)$ satisfying
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}\left(x\right)g(x)\
>  dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)\ dx$ for any $g\in L^{2}\left([0,1]\right)$.
>   Prove that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_{n}\|_{p}=\|f\|_{p}$, then
>   $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|f_{n}-f\|_{p}=0$.

I don't know how to approach to this question. Weak convergence does
NOT imply the subsequence convergence. And I expanded $|f_{n}-f|^{p}$
but nothing I can obtain. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try looking up here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/weak-convergence-in-lp-plus-convergence-of-norm-implies-strong-convergence

Comment: @Harnak I already looked it up. But it's a little different.

Comment: In what is it different? I think $g \in L^q$ by the way, cause that's the weak convergence for $L^p$

Comment: If you want an answer that follows the formulation in Stein and Shakarchi, you can find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4555474/291842).

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, for $p=2$.

$$
\|\,f_n-f\|^2=(\,f_n-f,f_n-f)=(\,f_n,f_n-f)-(\,f,f_n-f)
$$
and clearly $(\,f,f_n-f)\to 0$. Also
$$
(\,f_n,f_n-f)=(\,f_n,f_n)-(f_n,f)\to \|\,f\|^2-\|\,f\|^2=0,
$$
and finally, $\|\,f_n-f\|\to 0$.

Comment: It's only partial. I know it already.

Comment: While a partial answer (and identified as such), this clears away a good bit of the easily answered parts.