# $L^p$ convergence follows from $L^2$ convergence plus $L^p$ boundedness?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f_n$ is sequence of functions such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Also suppose $\|f_n\|_p\leqslant C \|f\|_p$, where constant $C$ is independent of $n$. From this data, can we conclude that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$? Assume $1<p<\infty$.

Comment: Any restriction on $p$?

Comment: $1<p<\infty$, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. For $p \in (1,\infty)$, $p \ne 2$ you can always achieve
$g_n \to 0$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but $\|g_n\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)} = 1$. For this, it is sufficient to consider
$$g_n = \chi_{(0,\alpha_n)} \, \beta_n$$
for suitably chosen scalars $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$. Finally, pick your favorite $f \in L^2(\mathbb R) \cap L^p(\mathbb R) \setminus \{0\}$ and consider $f_n = g_n + f$.

Comment: I guess u misunderstood the problem, whatever u are saying is okay but not pertinent to this problem. We are given $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ and $L^p$ boundedness. Did u use these both assumptions?

Comment: u took $f=0$, then $\|f\|_p = 0$, so its not $L^p$ bounded.

Comment: @RakeshBalhara This can be easily fixed. Take any $f\in L^2\cap L^p$ with $\|f\|_p = 1$ and $f_n$ as above. Then $f_n+f\to f$ in $L^2$, $\|f_n+f\|_p\leq \|f_n\|_p+\|f\|_p = 1+\|f\|_p = 2 = 2\|f\|_p$. Obviously $f_n+f\not\to f$ in $L^p$.

Comment: I edited my answer to obtain $f \ne 0$. Finally, you should bear in mind that your assertion holds for $C = 1$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/weak-convergence-in-lp-plus-convergence-of-norm-implies-strong-convergence.