# About weak convergence and convergence of norms

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Today in an exam on functional analysis the following question was posed:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb{N}} \subseteq H$ be a sequence that converges weakly to $x\in H$ satisfying $\|x_n\|\to \|x\|$ as $n\to \infty$.
Show that $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ converges strongly to $x$.

I am aware of a proof based writing the norm with the scalar product.

I was wondering whether this also holds under weaker assumptions and found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163209).
My question basically is whether we can better classify where norm convergence or the $\limsup$ estimate in the quoted answer is sufficient or in the best case an equivalent description.

Comment: The keyword to search for is "Brezis-Lieb lemma". [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.4654) is a recent paper on the subject (Adimurthi-Tintarev 2014).

Comment: I had a look at this paper and the one by Brezis and Lieb but until now I failed to recognize how these give me a hint for me problem.