# Weak convergence, norm convergence, and convergence of norms

Tags: functional-analysis

If $x_n\to x$ in a normed space, then $\|x_n\|\to \|x\|$, and $x_n\to x$ weakly. If the space is finite-dimensional, or it is a Hilbert space, the converse is also true: weak convergence+convergence of the norms implies convergence in norm. Are there any other non-trivial examples when this converse implication holds? Or any counterexamples?

Comment: $\ell^1$ is another example where weak convergence implies that in norm (look up Schur's theorem).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/weak-convergence-in-lp-plus-convergence-of-norm-implies-strong-convergence

Comment: This identity is often called "Radon-riesz (or kadets-klee)" property. It is known that every uniformly convex (also known as uniformly rotund) normed space has the Radon-reisz property. See for example "An Introduction to Banach Space Theory, by Robert Megginson"  theorem 5.2.18

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, they answer my question perfectly. Uniform convexity is fascinating :-)

Comment: @vectorSpace That qualifies as answer, you can write it down below and ask user60121 to accept.