# If ${x_n}$ is weakly convergent to $x$ in $L^p(0,1)$ space, and if $\lim_{n}\|x_n\|=\|x\|$, then if $\lim_{n}x_n=x$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

If ${x_n}$ is weakly convergent to $x$ in $L^p(0,1)$ space, and if $\lim_{n}\|x_n\|=\|x\|$, then  if $\lim_{n}x_n=x$?

This question is from problem 6.1.4 in Avner Friedman's "Foundations of Modern Analysis".
The answer seems to be no since in $L_p(0,1)$ the parallelogram law is not fullfilled. But I cannot give a proof of this question and find a counter example.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/weak-convergence-in-lp-plus-convergence-of-norm-implies-strong-convergence).

Comment: Yes. The claim holds for every uniformly convex Banach space, and in particular for $L_p, \ 1<p<\infty$

Comment: Here $p\neq 2$.